# python django call chat.py in template $ajax ? giving error not found

Tags: python, ajax, django

hi i am new at python django.
i have template where i wana call a file through ajax

```
 $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "chat.py",
    data: {foo: 'bar', bar: 'foo'},
```

and `urls.py`

```
from django.conf.urls import include , url
from . import views
from . import chat

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.index, name='index'),

  url(r'^$', chat.main, name='main'),
]
```

and `chat.py`

```
import os
import sys

sys.path.append(os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))))
sys.path.append("../../tf_seq2seq_chatbot_parent")
import tensorflow as tf

from tf_seq2seq_chatbot.lib.chat import chat


def main(_):
    #chat()
    print('kjgjkh')

if __name__ == "__main__":
    tf.app.run()
```

and `views.py`

```
from django.shortcuts import render
def index(request):
    return render(request , "base.html" , {})

error: poll/chat.py not found
```

Comment: where is chat.py located in the directory structure?

Answer (score 0):

You haven't got a URL "chat.py". Your URLs are defined in the regexes in your urls.py; but you've only defined one, which is just /, although you've defined it twice which can't possibly work.

Make those two URLs different, and use the one you want in your Ajax call.

Comment: i am not getting .if i have two files chat.py and views.py then how can i set urls?

Comment: I don't understand what having two files has to do with it. You need to define an actual URL, which you haven't.

Comment: dear i set this url from views.py url(r'^$', views.index, name='index'), for my template its working.now my target is that i have to send ajax call at chat.py thats giving error not found.although its placed in same directory as where views.py.

Comment: Yes because instead of giving it its own URL you set it to the same as the index URL. That **does not work**. A thing on the web needs to have its own URL, how is that not clear?

Comment: ok dear you mean i have to set like this url(r'^main$', chat.main, name='main'), with other name?

Comment: and now if i am putting url:chat.py then its same error

Comment: Because now your URL is "/main". (And please don't call me "dear", you're not my wife.)

Comment: hi Brain i have red already its view function url but i have to go chat.py thats why giving error

Comment: url(r'^chat$', chat.main, name='chat'), and then in your ajax request: url: "/chat",